# @ Symbols in PHP comments being read as code?

Tags: php, comments

So I started using this little library for creating a RESTful PHP server, right [here](https://github.com/jacwright/RestServer).

In the code, I noticed that it appears that the comments are actually significant, in other words, if I change the comments, it actually changes the behavior of the code. Is this normal practice? I've never seen this used before and it seems weird to me to not ignore comments.

```
class TestController
{
    /**
     * Returns a JSON string object to the browser when hitting the root of the domain
     *
     * @url GET /
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    /**
     * Logs in a user with the given username and password POSTed. Though true
     * REST doesn't believe in sessions, it is often desirable for an AJAX server.
     *
     * @url POST /login
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password']; //@todo remove since it is not needed anywhere
        return array("success" => "Logged in " . $username);
    }
    /**
     * Gets the user by id or current user
     *
     * @url GET /users/$id
     * @url GET /users/current
     */
    public function getUser($id = null)
    {
        // if ($id) {
        //     $user = User::load($id); // possible user loading method
        // } else {
        //     $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        // }
        return array("id" => $id, "name" => null); // serializes object into JSON
    }
```

Basically, the @url blocks actually define what request types to which URLs call the function below them. What is the scope of this, does it have to be the @lines right above the function? Is this standard PHP practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is PHP Doc. See https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html and specifically https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/docblocks.html#tags

> A tag always starts on a new line with an at-sign (@) followed by the name of the tag. Between the start of the line and the tag’s name (including at-sign) there may be one or more spaces or tabs.

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is exactly where they got the standard

Answer (score 1):

Erm... Yes and No!

No, in the sense that it's not a normal PHP feature. In PHP, a comment is a comment and PHP makes no attempt to parse its content.

Yes in the sense that because PHP won't parse the comment, developers sometimes use it as a place to store data for their libraries. The Symfony framework is a good example.

In this case, the library you installed is parsing the comments in the class `RestServer.php` itself. You can read the class yourself, although there's some pretty hardcore PHP and Regex in there.